# объясните сокращенный вариант присваивания

Tags: javascript

```js
function pow(x, n) {
  var res = x;
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    // x *= x;  81
    res *= x; // 27 
  }
  return console.log((res))
}

pow(3, 3)
```

Я что-то не догнал (пример) при `var a  = 10` будет `10`, присваиваем `var a = 20` будет `20` в цикле  `res *= x` работать будет так `res =  res  * x`, `res == 9` откуда там взялась `27` ?

Comment: Цикл проходит две итерации. В первом случае 9, во втором - 27

Comment: @Misha Saidov   на первой же итерации res * x это будет res = 9; так как вычисления в цикле не закончилось (2 итерация) res = 9* 3; res == 27; правильно ?

Comment: Именно. А автор скрипта в комментарии сразу указал результат, который получится в самой последней итерации.

Comment: @ Misha Saidov спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На первой же итерации `res * x` это будет `res = 9;` так как вычисления в цикле не закончилось ***2 итерация*** `res = 9* 3;  res == 27;`

Comment: `res *= x` это сокращение для `res = res * x`, а не для `res = x * x`

Comment: @ Igor  сори опечатка